# 6.5 month old still not feeding enough

Tags: feeding

Here's her feeding schedule, all expressed milk in bottle:

7:00AM: 3 Oz

11:00AM: 3 Oz

12:00 Noon: ~ 2Oz of solids (cereal or avacado or prune mixed with milk)

3:00PM: 6 Oz (really hungry)

7:00PM: 4 Oz + some breast feeding after her mom comes home (maybe another 2Oz)
(Mostly sleeps through the night without need to feed).

As you can see, she takes in a total of 16-18 oz + 2oz of solids in a 24-hr period. She's 16 lbs and 9 oz.

We usually heat a 6 oz bottle, and she would suck and mostly would stop sucking after 3,4 ozs, just turns her head or closes her mouth. And sometimes she would not suck at all and we'd need to wait 10-15 mins and she may suck another 2,3 oz. Everytime it's a struggle to get her to take the full 6 oz.

What can I do to get her to feed more (or is this normal as is?) She otherwise is happy and almost would never cry for food (unless we wait like 6 hours during the day to feed her).

Comment: She takes nothing at night? Is she gaining weight? Does your pediatrician have concerns? If she's gaining weight nicely, is happy, and doesn't complain of hunger, I'm not sure why you're concerned.

Comment: Yes she takes nothing at night. She is gaining weight but slower than usual, and is dropping on the percentage curve every week. Pediatrician doesn't have any particular concern but doesn't have any good suggestions either.

She is happy yes.

Comment: There are many cultures around the world that encourage fat babies as a sign of good parenting. If this is the pressure you feel, please know that if your doctor is not concerned and your child is gaining weight, it is likely perfectly okay.  Just let the people with opinions know that the doctor says the baby is healthy. If other concerns are added -- like a rash, lethargy, a change in development, do return to your doctor. It does sound like everything is fine and that you  are like most  parents everywhere and you are  lovingly concerned.

Comment: Weight looks good.  She may be dropping on the chart, but as long as she isn't losing weight I wouldn't get too concerned yet.

Comment: You might want to chart her on a growth curve specifically for breast fed babies.

Comment: My pediatrician said "Don't look at the chart, look at the baby".  If the baby has access to food, and is active and happy, nothing's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A healthy baby knows when she's hungry and when she isn't, and she knows how to tell you. If you're wondering if she's healthy, you need to ask her doctor, not us. But don't force her to drink more than she wants to unless there's a medical condition that justifies such an action.

Encouraging a baby to eat more than she wants to can lead to bad habits, and encourages the risk for weight related issues later in her life. See every result on the first few pages when searching for "[can babies eat to much](https://www.google.ch/search?q=can%20babies%20eat%20too%20much)" with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for healthy babies to drop in percentiles for weight. Mine and many of my friends' babies have and they are fine. Still it's rare for a breastfeeding baby to not nurse at night with only one portion solids. I'd encourage a breastfeeding session right before Mom goes to bed (a "dreamfeed") which is done while the baby is asleep. If baby nurses, great. If not, no harm done.